# select * from (select...) sqlite python

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a sqlite database and try to make a special request between two tables.
In the first table (table1 for example), i have two columns named "reference" and "ID". I want to search an ID in it, get it value in "reference" and display all informations from the table which have this value as name.
I try to find something on the internet but I didn't find an answer.

This is the request I made:

```
select * from (select Reference from table1 where Name='Value1')
```

It only give me the result of

```
select Reference from table1 where Name='Value1'
```

EDIT:
I want

```
select Reference from table1 where Name='Value1' => name of table
select * from name of table => show all elements
```

I'm new in sqlite but I hope you can help me.

Thank you by advance

Matt

Comment: The two examples you have show are identical. What did you expect the first one to do?

Comment: The second request give me the name of a table and I want to get all informations from this table.
I edit my post, hope it will be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't think there's a way to do it in sql completely (or at least not in a portable way). I'd recommend one of 3 solutions:

- Do exactly what you want, but do some processing in Python. That means query your master table, then construct new query based on each of the rows returned.
- If you have many tables, possibly changing dynamically - it may be a good idea to rethink your database design. Maybe you can move some of the changing table names into a new column and put your data in one table?
- If you have only a few tables available as the Reference and they never change, you could join all the possible tables, like:

  SELECT ... FROM table1
      LEFT JOIN table2
             ON table1.id = table2.id AND table1.Reference = "table2"
      LEFT JOIN table3 ...

But you may need to explain it all a bit better...

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your response, I already thought about processing in Python.
Because I am new in sql I asked to know if there is some tricks I don't understand/know.
I will choose the Python's solution.
Thank you